# Regex Clean transformation error

Tags: regex, ssis

I have used RegexClean Transformation to Replace my data

```
  match :  ('*SD)(?:'')*
  replace : SANDISK
```

It is replacing the words SD into SANDISK but it is not giving any space after transformation for example

```
MSD is getting converted to M SANDISK
but it is giving it as MSANDISK
```

It is showing good for words which have space from before that is

```
M SD is getting converted to M SANDISK
```

Comment: What are you trying to replace again?

Comment: replace SD with SANDISK

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match `SD` as a separate word, try this regex:

```
match: (^|[ \t\n\r\f])SD([ \t\n\r\f]|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This thing is not converting MSD to M SANDISK It is just just converting M SD to MSANDISK but i need it as M SANDISK

Comment: Ok. So the problem is not with regex, but only with `replace`.  Did you try adding spaces like this: "replace :  SANDISK "?

Comment: Is there a site that generates the picture to go along with regex? That looks amazingly useful